# hide view in interface builder when there are multiple views

Tags: iphone

This is probably a dumb question, but I can't seem to figure it out.  In IB, if I have two UIViews, that are subviews of the main UIViewController.view that I basically show and hide depending on the user's input, is there a way to hide one of the views while working in IB.  All the text/buttons are on top of each other so I can't really tell what's going on.  Is there a way to just make that view and all its children hidden while I work on the other view?  Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean under "hide" ? Are you talking about imageViews with images or what? may be you add a screen-shot?

Comment: @Stas Since I have two UIViews that are both subclasses of the main view, if each one has a label at the same location, the labels are on top of each other.  I'd like to be able to "disable" or "hide" the first UIView and all of its children so I can work with the second UIView and see what it would look like without the obstruction of the first UIView.

Comment: I suggested an easy alternative that is also hacky, but doesn't require a change to your layouts, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264235/why-does-interface-builder-show-hidden-views-through-the-views-above-them?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd suggest temporarily dragging one of the views outside of the UIViewController.view while you do everything in IB, and then dragging it back after you're done.

Comment: It's a bit depressing that this is the best answer!  Even just a show/hide layer thing like the Photoshop layers panel would be handy.

Comment: with ya, Marcin. this would be extremely useful.  thanks yuji.

Comment: It's a bit sad when you have constraints being reset.

Comment: One of many things XCode is lacking. If I'm not working with many constraints I just drag out another view controller and use that for editing views by just dragging the view that needs editing there then back after I've finished editing.

Comment: If you are working with constraints, you can click on the item, show the Size Inspector, click Edit on one of your X/Y constraints (such as Leading Space to: Superview), and add or subtract 1,000.  Then put it back when you're done. (But yes, sad; Apple should add a legitimate show/hide.)

Comment: I won't downvote you, but you should mention in your answer that if you do this, that you will lose all constraints on these views.  This can be frustrating and lead to lost work.

Comment: I would suggest not editing the constraint. Just edit the frame, put the view like at x 1000. Then at runtime (also in the preview assistant) the view will be correctly shown because of the untouched constraint. You won't need to remember to edit any values back.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone comes back to this question: in the newest XCode, you can open Assistant Editor with Preview and see what's happening in the Preview while working on the xib (e.g. when you hide a view).

EDIT: doesn't seem to work in XCode 8 any more.

Comment: Even the preview does not care for if a view is hidden or not. It just always shows it. Stupid Interface Builder. (Xcode 8)

Comment: Oh. You're right. It seems they've changed it. What sense does it make? Strange :/

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, provided your views are opaque: in the Document Outline in IB, just click and drag the view you **don't** want to see so it's listed above the view you **do** want to see. Leave it there until you're done with your work, and then just remember to drag it back down before you test.

This also has the side-benefit of not breaking or altering any existing auto layout constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Select the view you temporally didn't want to edit, and in the inspector panel, select attributes inspector, unselect the installed, when you done with your modify, click installed back.
Be ware with your constrains.