# Why does Interface Builder show hidden views through the views above them?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

When nesting views in Interface Builder, if I have an opaque view with hidden views beneath it in the view Hierarchy, the hidden views are visible through the higher view and are just partially translucent like the below picture.

Why does this happen and can I make it stop? It's very annoying.

To be clear this is strictly in IB. At run time the  views are displayed correctly.

[image]

Comment: So you can build your interface.  If you don't want them to show up, put them in xib's and programmatically add/remove them when needed.

Comment: Gothca, I was afraid that was the case. Itll be easier I think to just leave them all showing while building my interface and set them to hidden later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad to see this is the best answer that I have found so far: If you set the view you want to work as NOT hidden, while all the rest ARE hidden, then you can select away from the storyboard (e.g. some other file), then click back on the storyboard. Only the NON-hidden views are displayed. Sadly, the other views comeback if you make position alterations to the view (**UPDATE**: only when you click and drag. Selecting and using arrow keys does not), but changing text, size, color etc do not.

Original with hidden
[image: Original with hidden]

Clicked off storyboard and back
[image: Clicked off storyboard and back]

Comment: Better than nothing I guess. Indeed this is sad. I can't imagine any actual use for this "feature". I'd love to ask Apple why they made IB do this, it seems so pointless